# UnderscoreJS - How to Flatten Nested Properties

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have JSON array as shown below:

```
[{
   'a': 1,
   'b': 10,
   'aa': { 'a': 11, 'ab': 110 }
}, {
   'a': 2,
   'b': 20,
   'aa': { 'a': 22, 'ab': 220 }
}, {
   'a': 3,
   'b': 30,
   'aa': { 'a': 33, 'ab': 330 }
}, ...]
```

**Edit:**
The array mentioned here is Dynamic. And it could have more or less elements than specified here.

And using `Underscore`, I want to Flatten this array so that I can get below output:

```
[{ 'a': 1},
{ 'a': 11 }, 
{ 'a': 2 },
{ 'a': 22 }, 
{ 'a': 3 },
{ 'a': 33 }]
```

Comment: Why not just vanilla JS? It's just as easy, no need for a library

Comment: How about ` array.flatten(); `?

Comment: Its dynamic array. Not static one.

Comment: `_.chain(arr).union(_.pluck(arr, 'aa')).map( x => ({a: x.a}) ).value()`

Answer (score 3):

I could not find a proper method to do this in UnderscoreJS since it is not achievable with a simple array flattening.

You could do this with plain JavaScript like this:

```js
const source = [{
   'a': 1,
   'b': 10,
   'aa': { 'a': 11, 'ab': 110 }
}, {
   'a': 2,
   'b': 20,
   'aa': { 'a': 22, 'ab': 220 }
}, {
   'a': 3,
   'b': 30,
   'aa': { 'a': 33, 'ab': 330 }
}];

const result = source.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc.push({a: item.a});
  acc.push({a: item.aa.a});
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Its dynamic array. Not static one

Comment: @user2988458 -- So please specify the dynamic behaviour so that I can update my code. Please edit your question and include all the necessary details.

Comment: @user2988458 -- The question still doesn't include the behaviour of dynamicity.

Comment: "And it could have more or less elements than specified here."

Comment: So property name would remain same but number of elements may differ.

Answer (score 2):

If vanilla JS is OK, I would use `reduce`:

```js
const input = [{
   'a': 1,
   'b': 10,
   'aa': { 'a': 11, 'ab': 110 }
}, {
   'a': 2,
   'b': 20,
   'aa': { 'a': 22, 'ab': 220 }
}, {
   'a': 3,
   'b': 30,
   'aa': { 'a': 33, 'ab': 330 }
}];

const output = input.reduce(
  (arr, { a: a1, aa: { a: a2 }}) => [...arr, { a: a1 }, { a: a2 }],
  []
);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Its dynamic array. Not static one

Comment: Please include all necessary information in your question *before* people start to answer it...

Comment: I don't understand the issue. The code I posted doesn't depend on the number of elements in `input`, and if the property names are the same, it should work fine.

Comment: I'll check this and mark it as an answer if it works.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about underscore, but with vanilla javascript you can make a function that will recursively drill down into an object looking for a particular key. You can then call that function on each item in the array using `reduce()`. Something like this should be a good start and should work with arbitrarily nested objects:

```js
let arr  = [{'a': 1,'b': 10,'aa': { 'a': 11, 'ab': 110 }}, {'a': 2,'b': 20,'aa': { 'a': 22, 'ab': 220 }}, {'a': 3,'b': 30,'aa': { 'a': 33, 'ab': 330 }}]

 function getAll(obj, key, arr = []) {
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, v]) => {
        if (k === key) arr.push({[k]:v})
        else if (typeof v === 'object')   getAll(v, key, arr)
    })
    return arr
 }
 let key = 'a'
 let ret = arr.reduce((a, c) => a.concat(getAll(c, key)), [])
 console.log(ret)
```

You could also combine this into a single `reduce()` but it might start getting a little hard to grok:

```js
let arr  = [{'a': 1,'b': 10,'aa': { 'a': 11, 'ab': {'a': 'mark was here'} }}, {'a': 2,'b': 20,'aa': { 'a': 22, 'ab': 220 }}, {'a': 3,'b': 30,'aa': { 'a': 33, 'ab': 330 }}]
let key = 'a'
let ret = arr.reduce(function getall(a, c){
    Object.entries(c).forEach(([k,v]) => {
        if (k === key) a.push({[k]: v})
        else if (typeof v === 'object') getall(a, v)
    })
    return a
}, [])
   
 

 console.log(ret)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a recursive solution that uses [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), and [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate the keys and values (entries) of a nested object. If the key is found, it's entry is added to the result. If the value is an array or object (unless it's the key we're looking for), the value is iterated, and the search continues.

```js
const source = [{
   'a': 1,
   'b': 10,
   'aa': { 'a': 11, 'ab': 110 }
}, {
   'a': 2,
   'b': 20,
   'aa': { 'a': 22, 'ab': 220 }
}, {
   'a': 3,
   'b': 30,
   'aa': { 'a': 33, 'ab': { 'a': 500 } } // added another nested 'a'
}];

const getKey = (src, key) => {
  const result = [];
  
  const inner = (src) =>
    Object.entries(src)
      .forEach(([k, v]) => {
        if(k === key) result.push({ [k]: v });
        else if(v && typeof v === 'object') inner(v);
      });
      
  inner(src);
  
  return result;
}

console.log(getKey(source, 'a'));
```